Return a column with more than 16384 bytes
I am using a sybase ase 15 database. And I have a column of type image (this column stores SQL querys) so I have to convert it to varchar to return the text. The problem is that I can't return more than 16834 bytes, and it returns the query trimmed.
Is there any way to get the whole column? I am currently using a script with the pymssql library in python.
And the query I am using is
select (convert varchar(16834), convert(varbinary(16834), FIELD)) as 'SQL' from TABLE WHERE ...

I've tried to put max instead 16834, but it returns error as don't recognize as variable, cast it to TEXT type, but it doesn't return the full size of the column either. The column datatype is IMAGE and the heavier field is 40kb, but it only returns 16kb

In transact-sql you can just reference the column (no functions necessary) and ASE will return the entire contents of the column, eg, the following should be sufficient:
select FIELD from TABLE

NOTE: I don't work with python/pmssql but I would expect it to know how to process the long stream of data returned from a text/image datatype.
If for some reason python/pmmsql doesn't have the ability to process a single, long stream of data then you may want to look at the readtext command to break the data into chunks.
A basic example of using readtext to read a chunk of data from a column:
declare @val varbinary(16) 

select @val = textptr(copy)        -- obtain the text pointer for <column_name>
from   blurbs                      -- from <table_name>
where  au_id = "648-92-1872" 

readtext blurbs.copy               -- <table_name>.<column_name> being read
@val 1 5                           -- text pointer, offset, length

In this case we're reading the first 5 bytes. In your case you'd use a loop to repeatedly call readtext for subsequent 16K chunks (ie, @val 1 16384, @val 16385 16384, @val 32769 16384, ...). (or as PeByte has figured out: make a single readtext call where the last arg is the result of datelength(<column_name>))
References:

ASE: Reference Manual: Commands: readtext
ASE: T-SQL Guide: Select Text, Unitext, and Image Values


Image datatype is BINARY not TEXT...

@sqlpro yes, I'm aware of the difference between the image (binary) and text (text) datatypes; what's your point?

Thanks! It worked, when I executed the query with pymssql the result is already parsed

@PeByte yeah, that should be a (somewhat) basic feature of any database/query tool; good to hear it was just a simple change

As markp-fuso said you can use readtext, the only thing i added is datalength to use the size correctly.
select @len = datalength (field) ... 
readtext table.column @val 0 @len


good point re: using datalength() so you only need a single readtext call; while I understand the16K limits on convert() calls I got sidetracked thinking you had some explicit reason for pulling the data back in 16K chunks hence the mention of a loop to repeatedly run readtext
